# Spatial separable convolution

Tags: tensorflow

How can I efficiently implement an 1x1 convolution which has separate filers along spatial dimension in Tensorflow? There is a [tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/nn.html#depthwise_conv2d) which is similar to my problem, but it has separate filters across *depth* (i.e. 3rd dimension).

In the simplest case out_channels = 1 this convolution can be written as:

```
def spatial_conv(input, filter):
  return tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(input, filter), [3], keep_dims=True)
```

where `input.dim=[batch_size, input_width, input_height, channels]` and `filter.dim=[input_width, input_height, channels]`. I want to generalize this convolution by concatenating the outputs from the same input and different (but the same shape) filters.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're looking for something like https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/master/doc/convolution.md#nn.SpatialConvolutionLocal in Torch. Though, mind that at the moment CUDA (cunn module) implementation has some terrible bug which makes CUDA performance even worse than CPU.